# AttributeError: 'gurobipy.LinExpr' object has no attribute '__colno__'

Tags: python, gurobi

I am trying to model a MILP problem using Python with Gurobi Solver. I have the latest Gurobi solver version. My problem started after I added a constraint with new function of gurobi **m.addGenConstrAbs** which add the abs value of the function as a constraint. Here is my code which create a gurobi feedback as:

**AttributeError: 'gurobipy.LinExpr' object has no attribute '__colno__'**.

My code which results with this feedback is:

```
for t in range(0,Period): 
 m.addGenConstrAbs(PEN[t], EG [t]+STG[t]-XXX, "PEN Constraint")
```

where **EG[t]**, **STD[t]** and **XXX** are decision variables.

I don't understand why Gurobi or Python returns with this error. What do you think the problem came from? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments to [Model.addGenConstrAbs()](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_model_addgenconstrabs.html) must be variables (`Var`), not linear expressions (`LinExpr`).  Try this:

```
for t in range(0,Period):
    z = m.addVar(lb=-GRB.INFINITY)
    m.addConstr(z == EG[t]+STG[t]-XXX)
    m.addGenConstrAbs(PEN[t], z, "PEN Constraint")
```

Comment: Thank you @Greg for your answer, it solved my problem. It seems I need to work on Gurobi returns to understand it more.